# How to build some sources of an autotools project using a non default compiler

Tags: autotools, automake

I have an autotools C project. The project has some tests that require MPI to build. It is easy to compile an MPI program using the mpicc "C Compiler" as this makes sure the MPI library is linked in without explicitly adding any flag to the LDFLAGS and LIBS variables.

Unfortunately, I am not familiar enough with the automake internals and not sure how I can change the compiler on the fly for some of the sources to be built. I guess I can do something along the following lines:

```
EXTRA_PROGRAMS = src/test/mpi_prog_1 \
                 src/test/mpi_prog_2

# MPICC defined in configure.ac
src/test/src_test_mpi_prog_1-mpi_prog_1.lo:
    libtool --tag=MPICC --mode=compile ...

src/test/src_test_mpi_prog_2-mpi_prog_2.lo:
    libtool --tag=MPICC --mode=compile ...
```

Would the rules for mpi_prog_1 and mpi_prog_2 override the automake default rules to build the MPI programs? How do I exactly hook automake with a custom build rule?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would the rules for mpi_prog_1 and mpi_prog_2 override the automake default rules to build the MPI programs? How do I exactly hook automake with a custom build rule?

According to the [Automake Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Extending.html):

> With some minor exceptions [...] the contents of a `Makefile.am` is
> copied to `Makefile.in` verbatim.
>
> These copying semantics mean that many problems can be worked around
> by simply adding some make variables and rules to `Makefile.am`.
> Automake will ignore these additions.
>
> [...] it is
> possible to have conflicting definitions of rules or variables. When
> building `Makefile.in` the following priorities are respected by
> `automake` to ensure the user always has the last word:
>
> - User defined variables in `Makefile.am` have priority over variables `AC_SUBST`ed from configure.ac, and `AC_SUBST`ed variables
>   have priority over `automake`-defined variables.
> - **As far as rules are concerned, a user-defined rule overrides any `automake`-defined rule for the same target**.

(Emphasis added)

So yes, if you provide custom rules -- which you do by putting them into your `Makefile.am` just as if it were a makefile -- then they will override any automatically-generated rules for building the same targets.

You can provide custom rules for other purposes, too, such as to provide for building files from sources that the autotools don't know about.  That's how you would engage a custom code generator, for example.